# Bixby: page might be empty warnings

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I'm really stuck and don't know what to do.
I've never worked in Bixby Studio and got that warning "page might be empty".
I've seen two similar posts about this problem, but they didn't help me at all.

```
            item-selection-question {
first warning-->          if (isFirstNavPage(page) && isLastNavPage(page)) {
                          template ("")
second warning-->       } else-if (!isLastNavPage(page)) {
                          template-macro (HANDS_FREE_OPTION_ITEM_SELECTION_MORE_PAGES)
                        } else {
                          template-macro (HANDS_FREE_OPTION_ITEM_SELECTION_LAST_PAGES)
                        }
                      }
                      overflow-statement {
                        template-macro (HANDS_FREE_OPTION_OVERFLOW_STATEMENT)
                      }
                      overflow-question {
                        template-macro (HANDS_FREE_OPTION_OVERFLOW_QUESTION)
                      }
                      page-marker {
third warning-->        if (!isFirstNavPage(page) && isLastNavPage(page)) {
                          template-macro (HANDS_FREE_OPTION_LAST_OPTION) {
                            param (page) {
                              expression (page)
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar warning for,

```
  content {
    template ("Here's #{value(audioInfo.audioItem[audioInfo.startAudioItemIndex].artist)}.") {
      speech ("Here's #{value(audioInfo.audioItem[audioInfo.startAudioItemIndex].title)}[ from #{value(audioInfo.audioItem[audioInfo.startAudioItemIndex].artist)}].")
    }
  }
```

**WARN audioInfo.startAudioItemIndex might be empty**

I changed the above snippet to,

```
  content {
    if(exists(audioInfo.startAudioItemIndex)){
      template ("Here's #{value(audioInfo.audioItem[audioInfo.startAudioItemIndex].artist)}.") {
        speech ("Here's #{value(audioInfo.audioItem[audioInfo.startAudioItemIndex].title)}[ from #{value(audioInfo.audioItem[audioInfo.startAudioItemIndex].artist)}].")
      }
    }
  }
```

And it no longer shows the warning.
Try and see if it helps.